# How to write columns in file in a loop one after another in C

Tags: c

I use this code like a test, all arrays will be calculated in a loop and then be written one after another to the file. I mean, new arrays will be calculated on the next step of the loop, and I want to add them one after another into the same file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int aa[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    FILE* ff;
    ff = fopen("file.txt","w+");
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        aa[i]+=j;
        fprintf(ff,"%d\n", aa[i]);
    }
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```

But I want to see the next result file:

```
1 2 4 7  11
2 3 5 8  12 
3 4 6 9  13
4 5 7 10 14
5 6 8 11 15
```

Comment: Files are generally written sequentially, especially text files. That is, one line at a time, not by column. You'll need to reorganize your code to write `aa[i]` and `bb[i]` each time through the loop.

Comment: Use a working file or write an output image in memory and then write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak both printf statement into one for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        fprintf(ff,"%d\t", aa[i]);
        fprintf(ff, "%d\n", bb[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This won't even leave a space between the two numbers. Additionally, it could be done in a single `fprintf` statement. I think that would be more readable as well.

Comment: Assuming that both aa and bb have 5 integers in them, when real logic is implemented take care of that, if they can have different number of entries, then logic would need to be changed....

Comment: yeah, but new arrays will be calculated on the next step of loop, and I want to add them one after another into the same file...

Comment: @LysandrosNikolaou I think `\t` can display space between two numbers, can't it? And true @deepakl, array sizes needs to be equal

Comment: @OlgaRi I am still unclear..can you elaborate so that I can update answer accordingly

Comment: @KaranDesai I calculate arrays in the loop, but I don't need to save all them and I want to write current array into the file, and at each step, I want to add new array to the same file

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int aa[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

int main(void){
    char lines[5][32];
    FILE *ff;

    ff = fopen("file.txt","w+");
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        rewind(ff);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){//Read the current file
            if(fscanf(ff, " %31[^\n]", lines[i]) != 1)
                *lines[i] = 0;
        }
        rewind(ff);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            aa[i] += j;
            fprintf(ff,"%s %-2d\n", lines[i], aa[i]);//Add data and export
        }
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```